# Getting the name of an object before it was changed using a handler

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to make sure a list of objects gets updated with an objects new name once it's renamed. The challenge I'm having is connecting the original name with the new name. I'm even more uncertain about when I rename multiple objects at once, either programmatically in another method, or using batch rename

This is what I have so far:

```
import bpy
curated_list=['Sphere.002','Sphere','Cube']
prenamess=[]

def prenames():
    for obj in bpy.dta.objects:
        prenamess+=[obj.name]
        
def postnames():
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        #find objects with name changed
        if obj.name not in prenamess:
            if obj.name in curated_list:
                #update curated list to match new name
                curated_list[prenamess.index(obj.name)]=obj.name
            #replace list of object names
print(curated_list)

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre.append(prenames)
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(postnames)
```

Comment: You might as well add a new custom property to all Object type and write the name you want it to have there, and add custom logic to make sure they are in sync. But I have trouble seeing your end goal here, would you mind adding a bit of info on your workflow ?

Comment: I've actually have now left the method described in the question and am using an object property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Limitation: Since objects pointer are lost after undo/redo, if you undo a batch rename operation, objects index will different and you don't know which object name changed

```
import bpy

OBJS = {obj : obj.name for obj in bpy.data.objects}

def postnames(dummy):
    for obj, old_name in OBJS.items():
        if obj.name != old_name:
            print(f"{old_name}  change to  {obj.name}")
            OBJS[obj] = obj.name

# objects address lost after undo/redo
def update_objects_pointer_after(dummy):
    global OBJS
    OBJS = {obj : obj.name for obj in bpy.data.objects}

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(postnames)
bpy.app.handlers.undo_post.append(update_objects_pointer_after)
bpy.app.handlers.redo_post.append(update_objects_pointer_after)
```